# Randomly generated CGGradient wont display

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, gradient

I'm writing an app that generates random gradients and displays them on the screen using a custom `UIView` Class. Because I have more planned functions for the app, I chose to give the gradient its own class. The code for generating the gradient is here:

```
import UIKit

class Gradient {

var topColor = UIColor()
var bottomColor = UIColor()
var gradient: CGGradientRef?

func generateGradient() -> CGGradientRef {

    var red = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256))
    var green = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256))
    var blue = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256))

    topColor = UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)

    red = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256))
    green = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256))
    blue = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256))

    bottomColor = UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)

    let gradientColors = [topColor.CGColor, bottomColor.CGColor]
    let gradientStops:[CGFloat] = [0, 1.0]
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

    let generatedGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, gradientColors, gradientStops)

    return generatedGradient

}

init() {
    gradient = self.generateGradient()
}

}
```

The gradient viewer class that displays the gradient reads:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class Gradient_Viewer: UIView {

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    let background = Gradient()
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    let startPoint = CGPoint.zeroPoint
    let endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.bounds.height)

    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, background.gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0)

}

}
```

Is there something wrong with the gradient generation, or am I not accessing the gradient properly?

Comment: What's the problem you're having?

Comment: The gradient I generate wont display in the view. It's just a white screen.

Comment: It appears that I need a random CGFloat from 0 to 1 rather than from 0 to 255. I'll try that.

Comment: I'm glad you got it sorted. You should add that as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@IBDesignable class Gradient_Viewer: UIView {
    var random8bit: CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256))/255.0
    }
    var gradient: CGGradientRef {
        return CGGradientCreateWithColors(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), [UIColor(red: random8bit, green: random8bit, blue: random8bit, alpha: 1.0).CGColor, UIColor(red: random8bit, green: random8bit, blue: random8bit, alpha: 1.0).CGColor], [0, 1.0])
    }
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        CGContextDrawLinearGradient(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), gradient, CGPoint.zeroPoint, CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.bounds.height), 0)
    }
}
```